# GRUB2: Configure multiple Windows and Linux operating systems on single EFI system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub2, windows-boot-manager

I've installed two instances of Windows 11 and one instance of Ubuntu 23.10 on my laptop with a single SSD.

After install my file system looks like this

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

nvme0n1            953.9G                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     100M /boot/efi                          
├─nvme0n1p2           16M                                    
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs   149.5G                                    
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     604M                                    
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     200G                                    
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs   310.7G                                    Shared
└─nvme0n1p7 ext4     293G / 

sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 245C7941-919B-4473-8B05-92AA2608EB88

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     239616  313743359 313503744 149.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4  313743360  314980351   1236992   604M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5  314980352  734410751 419430400   200G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p6  734410752 1386008575 651597824 310.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1386008576 2000406527 614397952   293G Linux filesystem
```

I ended up having a GRUB2 menu with following options:

```
 * Windows Boot Manager
 * Ubuntu 23.10
 * Additional Ubuntu Options
 * . . . . .
```

If I want to run one of the instances of Windows 11, I have to do next

1. Select Windows Boot Manager on first boot
2. Then select desired Windows 11 instance
3. PC reboots
4. Then again select Windows Boot Manager on second boot
5. Desired Windows 11 instance is loaded

I find this very lame, and further I come with with following question

**QUESTION** is it possible to reconfigure  GRUB that way that it is possible to load windows instances directly without the *Windows Boot Manager*?

Additional information:

bcdedit

```
C:\Windows\System32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {2ac3aa28-69bf-11ee-b9c2-cbeab994cd57}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             WINDOWS 11 (1)
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {2ac3aa28-69bf-11ee-b9c2-cbeab994cd57}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
quietboot               No
usefirmwarepcisettings  No
sos                     No

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             WINDOWS 11 (2)
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {2ac3aa26-69bf-11ee-b9c2-cbeab994cd57}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {2ac3aa24-69bf-11ee-b9c2-cbeab994cd57}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

diskpart

```
DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved            16 MB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Primary            149 GB   117 MB
  Partition 4    Recovery           604 MB   149 GB
  Partition 5    Primary            200 GB   150 GB
  Partition 6    Primary            310 GB   350 GB
  Partition 7    Unknown            292 GB   660 GB

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                NTFS   Partition    149 GB  Healthy
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    200 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2     E   Shared       NTFS   Partition    310 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 4                      NTFS   Partition    604 MB  Healthy    Hidden
```

bcdedit /enum firmware

```
C:\Windows\System32>bcdedit /enum firmware

Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {839d692b-6ccf-11ee-aba5-7404f1de8473}
                        {bootmgr}
                        {e8d05f83-69b3-11ee-a0d6-c8f52e4e3bd7}
                        {e8d05f84-69b3-11ee-a0d6-c8f52e4e3bd7}
                        {e8d05f85-69b3-11ee-a0d6-c8f52e4e3bd7}
timeout                 0

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {2ac3aa28-69bf-11ee-b9c2-cbeab994cd57}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {839d692b-6ccf-11ee-aba5-7404f1de8473}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
description             ubuntu

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {e8d05f83-69b3-11ee-a0d6-c8f52e4e3bd7}
description             EFI USB Device

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {e8d05f84-69b3-11ee-a0d6-c8f52e4e3bd7}
description             EFI DVD/CDROM

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {e8d05f85-69b3-11ee-a0d6-c8f52e4e3bd7}
description             EFI Network
```

Comment: Though I've used the GUI Grub Customizer, https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-grub-customizer-on-linux-all-major-distros, with good results, use caution: a mistake (e.g., bad font) can make the PC unbootable. Make a disk image before attempting Grub2 tweaks.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've tried GRUB customizer and ended up having errors on save, something related to the discovery of windows boot manager with os-prober, I will to fix it with `boot-repair`

Comment: No, Boot Repair is not for that. I strongly advise, going forward, to not change anything. The Windows bootloader manager is designed to work like that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So there are no real ways to boot multiple windowses from the grub directly? The only option is to access with Windows Boot Manager?

Comment: There are No good/safe ways. Is it such an inconvenience to do the two steps?

Comment: You can get what you want by using Windows 11 as host and then the other machines as virtual machines.   Works better for me

Comment: @ChanganAuto is it possible to create multiple EFI partitions, for instance I want to split Windows Boot Loader into two separate things so they can load windows instances directly?

Comment: No. More than one ESP is possible but not recommended and in any case NEVER in the same drive but that's a moot point anyway because the lastly installed Windows taskes control of the boot manager (then Grub merely chainloads to that manager). Thousands have asked the same question and the answer has been, invariably, NO. Have a nice day.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thank you bro, good insight, then my guess is to try using an additional SSD, I will install Ubuntu and second Windows instance on another driver and this must give me what I need.

Comment: So, you understood nothing.